# Need a better top hit/suggestion for Swift "unexpectedly found nil" questions in the "Questions that may already have your answer" list

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

The Swift error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" is a common error that new iOS or Swift users encounter as they struggle to grasp the concept of Optional types in the Swift language. Questions about this issue are frequently asked and closed as duplicates of [this community wiki question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32170456/2415822).

I noticed, however, that this question does not show up as a the top result (or even at all) on the list of "Questions that may already have your answer" on the Ask Question page.

[image: Ask Question]

As this Community Wiki post is the best source of answers to this broad question, how can we make sure users asking about this topic see this question?

Comment: How in the world do 3 of those posts have the exact same title?  Isn't there a filter for that?

Comment: @NobodyNada the aliens are definitively not guilty, also history.

Comment: I'm not normally a big fan of deleting questions, but holy cow some of those need to get gone.